# TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object-------maybe multiprocessing‘s problems

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning machine learning. When running a DDPG code framework, the following error occurred and I checked some information. It may be that the multiprocessing serialization of multiprocessing has a problem, but I am not too sure. If you can help me, I appreciate it!
[image: Error]

[image: Code]

Comment: Its not with multi processing but with wither the model weights trained on different version, or you are not having the right version of libraries

Comment: don't post the code as images